# How can I find out what the weather is like in a given location on a certain month?

Tags: online-resources, weather-and-climate

Is there a good weather forecast website that I can check the historical weather on a specific area?

To explain my situation:

I want to go to Key West around January 2017 for a vacation but I want to be sure about the temperature I will find there around January.
Depending on the history of previous temperatures, I will go on Jan/2017 or I will reschedule to Dec/2016.

Comment: You mean something like an [Almanac](http://www.almanac.com/weather/history/FL/Key%20West/2016-01-21) ?

Comment: Almanac is OK for a very specific day, but it won't give a month comparison, like "is the entire month this way or not?" | "How it compares with the last 5 years?". But thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: December and January will be very similar. This is also the high season in Key West so you should expect everything will be much more crowded and expensive.

Comment: Weatherspark.com [works well for this](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/26003/3067).

Comment: related: [Is there a website with historical temperatures?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36405/is-there-a-website-with-historical-temperatures)

Comment: @pnuts I already figured it out. The answers for this question are all great and solved my problem ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Weather Underground has a nice [trip planner](http://www.wunderground.com/travelplanner/index.asp) feature for exactly this use-case. Tell it where you're going and when and it will show you the average temperature and range for the last 20 years, how many days it rained, and other such historical weather data. You can play with the dates and see how much the results vary.

Comment: I guess this is the best solution. I remember a few years ago, I found something very similar to this trip planner, but I could provide a month and a range (ie. 3 years) and it would give me the graphic of average values temperature+amount of rain for the last 3 years on that month.

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia serves quite well for most major metropolitan areas.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florida_Keys#Climate
Click the "Show" button to show the historical weather by month.

Answer (score 3):

Weather.com provides information about averages and record highs and lows, as well as average precipitation.

Here's the data for Key West (scroll down below the calendar for averages and records):

https://weather.com/weather/monthly/l/USFL0244:1:US