# Is it windy and snowy in West Europe during end year?

Tags: europe, weather-and-climate, winter, western-europe

I would like to know whether is it windy on night and morning and snowy in West Europe during Christmas and New Year?

Especially for these countries and cities:

> Paris, Belgium, Amsterdam, Frankfurt, Zurich, Venice, Pisa, Rome.

While what I can find is their lowest temperature is various around -4°C to 5°C.

Comment: Traveling in those cities anytime outside May-September is an unpleasant experience. Likewise I wouldn't hope for snow anywhere except Zurich, it's quite rare during the beginning of winter.

Comment: It can be lovely in Paris in the winter, in spring, say from March, it is often very nice. Not hot but pleasant. Venice, Pisa and Rome are likely nice even longer. And even in Amsterdam you can have nice days in March, April and October.

Comment: @JonathanReez *can be* unpleasant, perhaps even *is likely to be* unpleasant, but it's not guaranteed. There can rarely be high-pressure east winter systems with cold crisp sunny weather from the east that can be most beautiful.

Comment: @phoog for a tourist who's walking around outside for 5-6 hours per day it's not a pleasant kind of weather. For a local who's spending maybe 30 minutes outside during the whole day (or even zero if driving), it's a different story.

Comment: @JonathanReez, I have been a tourist in Paris in winter, in spring and autumn and find those times of year often pleasant, if dressed for the weather. It is not just nice in May-September. Amsterdam and Belgium are less likely to be pleasant in winter but still well within pleasant in March to October (included). Further to the south (Italy) the weather can be pleasant even in winter, if not all the time. If a comment could get a down vote your would have one by now.

Comment: @JonathanReez that's a matter opinion, or, more likely, equipment. I've spent entire days outside in weather like that in the Netherlands. If you have proper clothing, temperatures of a couple of degrees below freezing are quite tolerable, especially in the absence of wind. To my mind, the disadvantage from a tourist's point of view is the low probability of encountering such weather.  Windy wet weather can be much harder to deal with even if the temperature is +5 or even +15 Celsius. I've heard (from a Canadian) a saying that there's no such thing as bad weather, only bad clothes.

Comment: @JonathanReez: just got back from AMS and Rome; both were pleasant. Rome was 22C daytime.

Comment: I also guess that bad clothes will lead to so called as "bad weather"..

Comment: It may be worth noting that, in practice, actual snow can feel a lot *less* chilly than mere cold rain, because it won't soak through your clothes the same way. Also, fresh snow is pretty. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find out what the weather is like in a given location on a certain month?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64136/how-can-i-find-out-what-the-weather-is-like-in-a-given-location-on-a-certain-mon)

Comment: I find it interesting how Belgium is listed next to a set of cities. The country is not *that* small (and the Ardennes will be quite different than, say, Oostende; more chance of snow in the Ardennes, more wind in Oostende).

Comment: "Traveling in those cities anytime outside May-September is an unpleasant experience." So, basically, you're condemning pretty much the entirety of western Europe for seven months of the year. That's a pretty ridiculous comment.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I live in Central Europe so I know what I'm talking about. I'd never spend a cent on travel during that time unless it was for work.

Comment: @JonathanReez I live in England and I think you have a very low tolerance for less-than-ideal weather.

Comment: You should go a lot farther North to Northern Scandinavia to have a decent chance of experiencing a white Christmas.

Comment: Venice, Pisa, Rome > no.  Paris, Belgium, Amsterdam> maybe.  Frankfurt, Zurich > probably.

Comment: It is some kind of crystal ball prophecy. In Germany (not only Frankfurt) cold winters have been rarer in the last years, but are still possible. From relatively high temperatures (5-10°C, 50 °F, more likely) and sun to snowbound streets and bitter frost (-10 °C, 10°F, rare) everything in between is possible.

Answer (score 10):

Snow is rather unlikely in all of your named destinations.
The most likely for snow is Zurich, which is still not guarantied.

We have had snow in the Netherlands (so also Amsterdam) for Christmas and the new year. But it is a very small chance of snow.
Same goes for Belgium, Paris and Frankfurt. Rain is much more likely and often comes with strong winds.
Italy is mostly a bit milder, with an even lower chance on snow and more chance on temperatures above the freezing points. But even there no guaranties, weather in Europe is unpredictable.

Whether you would like being a tourist in that time of year depends on what you are used to.
If you are used to winters well under the freezing point, you will find it pleasant, maybe a bit wet but not too cold.

But if you are used to mild winters that never dip under 15 C, with almost no wind, you may find it rather cold and nasty.

And if you are hoping for snow, plan to go up in the mountains in Switzerland or Italy. Around the end of the year you may find it hard to find any fresh snow, although most years will have some new snow in the mountains in November or December.

When coming from an area that does not have cold weather with driving winds, having just a short time, I would skip Amsterdam and the coastal area of Belgium. If you have a long time, say 2 months for your list, plan the visit to those areas when the weather predictions are the best.
In the other areas on your list you are less likely to have as strong winds in strong rain or it has a lot more to do inside. Paris has the Metro, which will allow you to travel out of the weather, which is much easier on your body when it is cold and windy.

Comment: I am a tourist that never experienced < 0°C though.. I am afraid it will be unpleasant experience for me, since some of the cities will be <0°C..

Comment: @Rendy you can dress for mild cold, you can't dress (well) for cold in combination with driving rain and gusty wind. Don't expect most of your destinations to be much below freezing (if at all) but expect wind chill to make it appear much colder than it really is.

Comment: I have lived in Zürich for five years and rarely saw any snow.

Comment: @jwenting Of course you can dress "well" for cold driving rain and gusty wind. All you need is a (light) outer layer than is waterproof and windproof, including a hood so your head doesn't get wet. The people who *live* in these weather conditions don't hibernate for several months of the year!

Comment: Living in the Netherlands I do not hibernate for months but I have to admit that I spend as little time outside as possible when it is =5 C, rain and a driving wind.

Comment: @alephzero Sure. But, when the weather is "bad" (for whatever definition of bad you want to use), you tend to stay indoors and say things like, "I don't really need to go shopping today; I'll go tomorrow instead." That's fine when you live there but not good for a tourist.

Answer (score 3):

Depends very much on the city. Climate is quite a bit different north and south of the Alps. Snow in Rome happens once every 30 years, Pisa would be very rare too. Zurich is the most likely to have snow, primarily since it has the highest altitude. Amsterdam tends to be very wind, Paris and Frankfurt less so.